# Div side-by-side alignment with YouTube video

Tags: html, css, alignment

While I understand that aligning two div's side by side is a common question, I am having a little bit of an issue getting the YouTube video and chat box to align next to each other. I should be using a span, since this would allow the chatbox in the same space as the youtube video correct? I'm still learning the ropes here in HTML. Here is what the page currently looks like:

Here is my current HTML code, the divs dealing with the youtube video is class name "youtube-video" and div dealing with the chat box is class "chat"

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>Chat</title>
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
            </head>

            <body>

                <div class="header-bar">
                    <div class="bar"></div>
                    <div class="dropshadow"></div>
                </div>

                <div class="DJ-text">Affinity FM DJ Room 
                    <span class="Chat-text">Chat</span>
                <div class="DJ-underline"></div>
                <div class="Chat-underline"></div></div>

                <div class="youtube-video" style="float: left;">

                    <iframe width="900px" height="500px" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/2GvIq2SpVFM" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

                </div>

                <div class="chat" style="float: left; padding: 0px 0px 0px 12px;">
                    <input type="text" class="chat-name" placeholder="Chat">
                    <div class="info-rect">Info</div>
                    <div class="chat-messages"></div>
                    <textarea placeholder="Join the conversation..."></textarea>
                    <div class="chat-status">Status: <span>Idle</span></div>
                </div>

                <script src="http://127.0.0.1:8080/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>

                <script>
                    (function() {
                        var getNode = function(s) {
                            return document.querySelector(s);
                        },

                        // Get required nodes
                        status = getNode('.chat-status span'),
                        messages = getNode('.chat-messages'), 
                        textarea = getNode('.chat textarea'),
                        chatName = getNode('.chat-name'),

                        statusDefault = status.textContent,    

                        setStatus = function(s){
                            status.textContent = s;

                            if(s !== statusDefault){
                                var delay = setTimeout(function(){
                                    setStatus(statusDefault);
                                    clearInterval(delay);
                                }, 3000);
                            }
                        };

                        //try connection
                        try{
                           var socket = io.connect('http://127.0.0.1:8080');
                        } catch(e){
                            //Set status to warn user
                        }

                        if(socket !== undefined){

                            //Listen for output
                            socket.on('output', function(data){
                                if(data.length){
                                    //Loop through results
                                    for(var x = 0; x < data.length; x = x + 1){
                                        var message = document.createElement('div');
                                        message.setAttribute('class', 'chat-message');
                                        message.textContent = ': ' + data[x].message;
                                        var name=document.createElement('span');
                                        name.setAttribute('class', 'userName');
                                        name.textContent = data[x].name;

                                        message.insertBefore(name, message.firstChild);

                                        //Append
                                        messages.appendChild(message);
                                        messages.insertBefore(message, messages.firstChild);
                                    }
                                }
                            });

                            //Listen for a status
                            socket.on('status', function(data){
                                setStatus((typeof data === 'object') ? data.message : data);

                                if(data.clear === true){
                                    textarea.value = '';
                                }
                            });

                            //Listen for keydown
                            textarea.addEventListener('keydown', function(event){
                                var self = this,
                                    name = chatName.value;

                                if(event.which === 13 && event.shiftKey === false){
                                    socket.emit('input', {
                                        name: name,
                                        message: self.value
                                    });
                                }
                            });
                        }

                    })();
                </script>
            </body>
        </html>
```

Here is my CSS for youtube-video and chat:

```
    body {
    background-color: #0f0f17;
    margin: 0px;
    width: 100%;
}

body,
textarea,
input {
    font: 13px "Raleway", sans-serif;
    color: #ffffff;

}

.bar{
    height: 115px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #15151d;   
}

.DJ-text{
    font-weight: 700;
    position:relative;left:50px;
    position:relative;top:80px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.Chat-text{
    position:relative;left:900px;
}

.DJ-underline{
    width: 900px;
    height: 1px;
    position:relative;top:20px;
    background-color: #3f3f45;
}

.Chat-underline{
    width: 400px;
    position:relative;left:-140px;
    float:right;
    height: 1px;
    position:relative;top:20px;
    background-color: #3f3f45;
}

/*.youtube-video{
    position: relative; left: 50px;
    position: relative; top: 130px;


}

.chat {
    max-width: 400px;
    background-color: #0f0f17;
    position:relative;left:1093px;
    position:relative;top:150px;
}*/

.chat-messages,
.chat-textarea,
.chat-name {
    border: 1px solid #1a1a23;
    background-color: #1a1a23;
}

.userName{
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #079ce0;
}

.chat-messages {
    width:100%;
    height:400px;
    overflow-y:scroll;
    padding:10px;
}

.chat-message {
    margin-bottom:10px;
}

.info-rect{
    height: 40px;
    width: 180px;
    padding:10px;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin:0;
    border:0;
    display: flex; 
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;  
    font-weight: 700;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.chat-name{
    height: 40px;
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 180px;
    padding:10px;
    border:0;
    margin:0;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    float:left;
    text-align: center;
}

.chat textarea {
    width:100%;
    padding:10px;
    margin:0;
    border-top:0;
    max-width:100%;
    border-top: 1px solid #0f0f17;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #1a1a23;
    border-right: 1px solid #1a1a23;
    border-left: 1px solid #1a1a23;
    background-color: #1a1a23;

}

.chat-status {
    color: #bbb;
    background-color: #0f0f17;
}

.info-rect,
.chat textarea,
.chat-name { 
    max-width: 100%; 
}
```

Using the code above supplied by @georges_user2251342, this is what the page looks like:

[image: Progress]

Here is the reference PSD: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WKL5I.jpg

Comment: So you want the video in left and chat box in right?

Comment: @Thinker yes correct, sorry should have specified that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is true what they say! If I understand correctly, by centering, you mean to put 2 things side by side, next to each other so to speak.

In your case, the "youtube-video" element and the "chat" element need to be put side by side with percentages, yes. However, I would use 66% with 33% for percentages instead of 80% with 20%. Because your "chat" element doesn't look good with just 20%. It looks crunched up.

Look at these :

(66%-33%) http://lespointscom.com/a/misc/demo/2016_06_18/main_4.html

(80%-20%) http://lespointscom.com/a/misc/demo/2016_06_18/main_5.html

AGAIN THE NEW HTML :

```
               <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
                <head>
                    <title>Chat</title>
                    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main6.css">
                </head>

                <body>

                    <div class="header-bar">
                        <div class="bar"></div>
                        <div class="dropshadow"></div>
                    </div>


                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="youtube-video">
                            <div class="DJ-text">Affinity FM DJ Room</div>
                            <div class="DJ-underline"></div>
                            <iframe class="iframe" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/2GvIq2SpVFM" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                        </div>

                        <div class="chat">
                            <div class="Chat-text">Chat</div>
                            <div class="Chat-underline"></div>
                            <input type="text" class="chat-name" placeholder="Chat">
                            <div class="info-rect">Info</div>
                            <div class="chat-messages"></div>
                            <textarea placeholder="Join the conversation..."></textarea>
                            <div class="chat-status">Status: <span>Idle</span></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <script src="http://127.0.0.1:8080/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>

                    <script>
                        (function() {
                            var getNode = function(s) {
                                return document.querySelector(s);
                            },

                            // Get required nodes
                            status = getNode('.chat-status span'),
                            messages = getNode('.chat-messages'), 
                            textarea = getNode('.chat textarea'),
                            chatName = getNode('.chat-name'),

                            statusDefault = status.textContent,    

                            setStatus = function(s){
                                status.textContent = s;

                                if(s !== statusDefault){
                                    var delay = setTimeout(function(){
                                        setStatus(statusDefault);
                                        clearInterval(delay);
                                    }, 3000);
                                }
                            };

                            //try connection
                            try{
                               var socket = io.connect('http://127.0.0.1:8080');
                            } catch(e){
                                //Set status to warn user
                            }

                            if(socket !== undefined){

                                //Listen for output
                                socket.on('output', function(data){
                                    if(data.length){
                                        //Loop through results
                                        for(var x = 0; x < data.length; x = x + 1){
                                            var message = document.createElement('div');
                                            message.setAttribute('class', 'chat-message');
                                            message.textContent = ': ' + data[x].message;
                                            var name=document.createElement('span');
                                            name.setAttribute('class', 'userName');
                                            name.textContent = data[x].name;

                                            message.insertBefore(name, message.firstChild);

                                            //Append
                                            messages.appendChild(message);
                                            messages.insertBefore(message, messages.firstChild);
                                        }
                                    }
                                });

                                //Listen for a status
                                socket.on('status', function(data){
                                    setStatus((typeof data === 'object') ? data.message : data);

                                    if(data.clear === true){
                                        textarea.value = '';
                                    }
                                });

                                //Listen for keydown
                                textarea.addEventListener('keydown', function(event){
                                    var self = this,
                                        name = chatName.value;

                                    if(event.which === 13 && event.shiftKey === false){
                                        socket.emit('input', {
                                            name: name,
                                            message: self.value
                                        });
                                    }
                                });
                            }

                        })();
                    </script>
                </body>
            </html>
```

AGAIN THE NEW CSS :

```
        .youtube-video{
            float: left;
            width:66%;
        }

        .chat {
            float: left;
            width:33%;
        }

        .iframe {
            width:98%;
            min-height:500px;
        }

        .container {
            width:98%;
        }

        body {
            background-color: #0f0f17;
            margin: 0px;
            width: 100%;
        }

        body,
        textarea,
        input {
            font: 13px "Raleway", sans-serif;
            color: #ffffff;

        }

        .bar{
            height: 115px;
            width: 100%;
            background-color: #15151d;   
        }

        .DJ-text{
            font-weight: 700;
            /*position:relative;
            left:50px;
            top:80px;*/
            text-transform: uppercase;
        }

        .Chat-text{
            font-weight: 700;
            /*position:relative;left:900px;*/
            text-transform: uppercase;
        }

        .DJ-underline{
            width: 98%;
            height: 1px;
            position:relative;top:20px;
            background-color: #3f3f45;
            margin: 0px 0px 50px;
        }

        .Chat-underline{
            width: 100%;
            position:relative;
            /*left:-140px;*/
            float:right;
            height: 1px;
            position:relative;top:20px;
            background-color: #3f3f45;
            margin: 0px 0px 50px;
        }
        .chat-messages,
        .chat-textarea,
        .chat-name {
            border: 1px solid #1a1a23;
            background-color: #1a1a23;
        }

        .userName{
            font-weight: 700;
            color: #079ce0;
        }

        .chat-messages {
            width:95%;
            height:400px;
            overflow-y:scroll;
            padding:10px;
        }

        .chat-message {
            margin-bottom:10px;
        }

        .info-rect{
            height: 40px;
            width: 180px;
            padding:10px;
            max-width: 100%;
            margin:0;
            border:0;
            display: flex; 
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;  
            font-weight: 700;
            text-transform: uppercase;
        }

        .chat-name{
            height: 40px;
            max-width: 100%;
            width: 180px;
            padding:10px;
            border:0;
            margin:0;
            font-weight: 700;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            float:left;
            text-align: center;
        }

        .chat textarea {
            width:95%;
            padding:10px;
            margin:0;
            border-top:0;
            max-width:100%;
            border-top: 1px solid #0f0f17;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #1a1a23;
            border-right: 1px solid #1a1a23;
            border-left: 1px solid #1a1a23;
            background-color: #1a1a23;

        }

        .chat-status {
            color: #bbb;
            background-color: #0f0f17;
        }

        .info-rect,
        .chat textarea,
        .chat-name { 
            max-width: 100%; 
        }


        @media only screen and (max-width: 772px) and (min-width: 0px)
        {
            .youtube-video{
                width:100%;
            }
            .chat{
                width:100%;
            }
        }




        @media only screen and (max-width: 1254px) and (min-width: 0px)
        {
            .info-rect{
                width:30%;
            }
        }
        @media only screen and (max-width: 1054px) and (min-width: 0px)
        {
            .info-rect{
                width:10%;
            }
        }
```

Comment: wonderful, this did the trick! Last question, what is the best way to center this on screen since someone here mentioned that shifting via pixels is a bad idea..? Thank you for your help. I'll rate this as best answer once I hear back from you on this

Comment: (responsive) http://lespointscom.com/a/misc/demo/2016_06_18/main_6.html


I took the trouble to make a responsive 66%-33% version just so you can make it even better. Because if the screen is smaller than 772px, nothing looks good. Try reducing the size of your browser with all 3 and notice the difference with the last one!

Answer (score 1):

You can bring the chat box to the right by using `position` property.

1. Add this css for `youtube-video`

   ```
   width:80%;
   height:100%;
   position:absolute;
   left:0;
   top:0;
   ```
2. Add this css for `chat`

   ```
   width:20%;
   height:100%;
   position:absolute;
   right:0;
   top:0;
   ```

So, by doing this, you can bring the chat box to right.

Here is the [Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/4KKPSAvQsxSYva7PzEo6?p=preview)

Hope it works for you :)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the suggestion! I've update the post to show what happens when I add your code to the css. The chatbox is indeed next to the video but the video/chat are now strangely offset (see image above). Is this just now a matter of tinkering with pixel values?

Comment: @JordanLewallen Dont mention the left value with pixel. Add it in percentage, so that it will be responsive in mobiles and ipads

Comment: does this go for the 'top' value as well then? I am having issues aligning these properly

Comment: you can apply the top value in pixels but specify the left value in percentage

Answer (score 0):

Just put a `float: left;` to both divs :

```
               <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
                <head>
                    <title>Chat</title>
                    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
                </head>

                <body>

                    <div class="header-bar">
                        <div class="bar"></div>
                        <div class="dropshadow"></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="DJ-text">Affinity FM DJ Room 
                        <span class="Chat-text">Chat</span>
                    <div class="DJ-underline"></div>
                    <div class="Chat-underline"></div></div>

                    <div class="youtube-video" style="float: left;">

                        <iframe width="900px" height="500px" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/2GvIq2SpVFM" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

                    </div>

                    <div class="chat" style="float: left; padding: 0px 0px 0px 12px;">
                        <input type="text" class="chat-name" placeholder="Chat">
                        <div class="info-rect">Info</div>
                        <div class="chat-messages"></div>
                        <textarea placeholder="Join the conversation..."></textarea>
                        <div class="chat-status">Status: <span>Idle</span></div>
                    </div>

                    <script src="http://127.0.0.1:8080/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>

                    <script>
                        (function() {
                            var getNode = function(s) {
                                return document.querySelector(s);
                            },

                            // Get required nodes
                            status = getNode('.chat-status span'),
                            messages = getNode('.chat-messages'), 
                            textarea = getNode('.chat textarea'),
                            chatName = getNode('.chat-name'),

                            statusDefault = status.textContent,    

                            setStatus = function(s){
                                status.textContent = s;

                                if(s !== statusDefault){
                                    var delay = setTimeout(function(){
                                        setStatus(statusDefault);
                                        clearInterval(delay);
                                    }, 3000);
                                }
                            };

                            //try connection
                            try{
                               var socket = io.connect('http://127.0.0.1:8080');
                            } catch(e){
                                //Set status to warn user
                            }

                            if(socket !== undefined){

                                //Listen for output
                                socket.on('output', function(data){
                                    if(data.length){
                                        //Loop through results
                                        for(var x = 0; x < data.length; x = x + 1){
                                            var message = document.createElement('div');
                                            message.setAttribute('class', 'chat-message');
                                            message.textContent = ': ' + data[x].message;
                                            var name=document.createElement('span');
                                            name.setAttribute('class', 'userName');
                                            name.textContent = data[x].name;

                                            message.insertBefore(name, message.firstChild);

                                            //Append
                                            messages.appendChild(message);
                                            messages.insertBefore(message, messages.firstChild);
                                        }
                                    }
                                });

                                //Listen for a status
                                socket.on('status', function(data){
                                    setStatus((typeof data === 'object') ? data.message : data);

                                    if(data.clear === true){
                                        textarea.value = '';
                                    }
                                });

                                //Listen for keydown
                                textarea.addEventListener('keydown', function(event){
                                    var self = this,
                                        name = chatName.value;

                                    if(event.which === 13 && event.shiftKey === false){
                                        socket.emit('input', {
                                            name: name,
                                            message: self.value
                                        });
                                    }
                                });
                            }

                        })();
                    </script>
                </body>
            </html>
```

and for a better look, add `padding: 0px 0px 0px 12px;` or a similar small padding to seperate both divs.

Comment: using your technique makes the chat box dissappear (nothing else is rearraged, it is just no longer on the page at all :(

Comment: Styles are cascading! That's very important to understand. Plus, we have to take into account the size of your screen. Can you give us your external style sheets? All the styles you use in order to reproduce what you see? Also, please tell us what browser you're using and is it full screen?

Comment: I've updated my original post using the code fixes you supplied along with the requested stylesheet in use. I added a screenshot of what the page now looks like along with a reference PSD that I am using (which I am trying to transfer to HTML/CSS!). Also, another user mentioned that left/right values should be programmed using percentages instead of pixels?

Comment: adding on to my above comment, I updated what the page currently looks like (refreshed editor and it was a tad different). I'm using chrome and full screen!

Answer (score 0):

1. Add this css for `youtube-video`

   width:80%;
   float:left;
2. Add this css for `chat`

   width:20%;
   float:left;

Comment: this didn't really work. It got the video and chat next to each other but the dimensions are all skewed now? http://imgur.com/Bwh0Xio

Comment: here is the psd I am currently working with. This is sorta what I'm shooting for: http://imgur.com/4XU62C9